# Get size of smaller image version

Tags: images

I am using this function to get the smaller version of an image and pass it on as featured image. However the `get_attachment` part and assigning to variable `$nsmall` doesn't seem to work. Any ideas what's wrong?

```
function acf_set_featured_image( $value, $post_id, $field  ){

    if($value != ''){
      $size = 'medium';
      $nsmall = wp_get_attachment_image( $value, $size );

      //Add the value which is the image ID to the _thumbnail_id meta data for the current post
      update_post_meta($post_id, '_thumbnail_id', $nsmall);
    }

    return $value;
}

// acf/update_value/name={$field_name} - filter for a specific field based on it's name
add_filter('acf/update_value/name=fl_image', 'acf_set_featured_image', 10, 3);
```